# C# Events - Raising, Subscribing from two different projects in one solution

Tags: c#, events

My goal is to create an event, raise the event in Project #1, have Project #2 subscribe to the event so that I can hit some code in Project #2. I was advised to do it this way because I cannot reference the code in Project #2.

I'm not familiar with events and have been researching the last hour. Is there anyone that can provide example code on how to do this? What I have now is not working.

```
// Creating the event

public event EventHandler UpdateUIEvent;

// Raising the event in Project #1

protected override void ResetProperties() 
{
    this.filePath = string.Empty;
    EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
    UpdateUIEvent(this, e);  // this kills my program
}

// Subscribing to the event in Project #2

protected override void ClearAll()
{
    boEncrypt.UpdateUIEvent += new EventHandler ?? // Not sure how to subscribe here
    tbFile.text = string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close... Please read [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx) as usual for a better understanding of what needs to be where.

For your code, here's what we'll do:

In project 1, incorporate Michael HB's good recommendation to always check if there's any subscribers.

```
public class ProjectOneClass
{
    public event EventHandler UpdateUIEvent;

    // other stuff     

    protected override void ResetProperties()
    {
        this.filePath = string.Empty;
        EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
        var handler = UpdateUIEvent;
        if (handler != null)
            UpdateUIEvent(this, e);
    }
}
```

Then in project 2, you have to have a reference to the event, which means you also need a reference to the class that contains it. You define a method in the class in project 2 that has the same signature as the event in project 1. In your case (in many cases) this signature is `void (object sender, EventArgs e)`. `EventHandler` is a pre-defined [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) with this signature.

"Subscribing" to the event is adding your new method to the handler, like `pOne.UpdateUIEvent += SomeMethodWithTheSameSignature;` You're basically saying "whenever UpdateUIEvent is called, call this other method as well".

So now that we know that we can have a method called when the event fires, we need to define that event. If you want to call `ClearAll()` when the event fires, that's what goes in the method body.

```
public class ProjectTwoClass
{
    public ProjectOneClass pOne;

    // other stuff

    public ProjectTwoClass()
    {
        pOne = new ProjectOneClass();
        pOne.UpdateUIEvent += POneOnUpdateUIEvent;
    }

    public void POneOnUpdateUIEvent(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        ClearAll();
    }

    private void ClearAll()
    {
        tbFile.Text = string.Empty; // could probably just call tbFile.Clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before raising an event, you should always check if it is not null.

```
protected override void ResetProperties()  
{
    this.filePath = string.Empty;
    EventArgs e = new EventArgs();
    var handler = UpdateUIEvent;
    if(handler != null)
       UpdateUIEvent(this, e);
}
```

Even when you are in different projects, you should only matter about the "public" keyword (internal or private won't work).

In project #2, you'll have

```
protected overeride void ClearAll() 
{
    boEncrypt.UpdateUIEvent += yourFunctionToTriggerWhenTheEventIsRaised;
    tbFile.text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Michael, thanks so much for your response. I have a couple questions. First, I don't need the "yourFunctionToTriggerWhenTheEventIsRaised", I only need to get inside the ClearAll() by subscribing to the UpdateUIEvent. So how do I do that without creating another function to trigger? Also, how do I get the handler to become active? When I run through this code, the handler is always null. Thank you so much!

Comment: The function I wrote was to subscribe to your event. If you need the clearAll to be the triggered function, you need somewhere to make the trigger as I did with yourFunctionToTriggerWhenTheEventIsRaised. It can be where you instanciate your object. That function must have the same signature as your event handler, so object type for the first parameter and EventArgs for the second. That function yourFunctionToTriggerWhenTheEventIsRaised should call clearAll after that.